# Poor SQL Server Update Trigger Performance

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, triggers, ssis

I am using SSIS to update 13000 rows in a table using SQL server 2008 R2, the table has an update trigger on it, without the trigger the update takes < 5 minutes, with the trigger it takes > 1 hour.

I would have expected it to take twice as long (< 10 minutes) with the trigger but it is taking way longer.  Can anyone give me any pointers for what might be causing this, or ways to fix the problem?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Dim].[Company]
(
[CompanyKey] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY , 
[Name] nCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
[City] nCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
[Country] nCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
[PostCode] nCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
[Continent] nCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
[EcconomicRegion] nCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
[ErdfAreaType] nCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
[PostCodeLong] nCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
[PostCodeLat] nCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
[Type] nCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
[NumEmployees] int NOT NULL, 
[AnnualRevenue] MONEY NOT NULL, 
[BalanceSheetTotal] MONEY NOT NULL, 
[OwnershipType] nCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
[MembershipType] nCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
[AccountManagerKey] INT NOT NULL 

CONSTRAINT [PK_Company] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CompanyKey] asc)
)
GO
CREATE INDEX [IX_Company_NameCityPostcode] ON [Dim].[Company] ([Name], [City], [PostCode])
GO
CREATE INDEX [IX_Company_Name] ON [Dim].[Company] ([Name])
GO
CREATE INDEX [IX_Company_City] ON [Dim].[Company] ([City])
GO
CREATE INDEX [IX_Company_Postcode] ON [Dim].[Company] ([PostCode])
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Dim].[Company_Update] ON [Dim].[Company] FOR UPDATE 
AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON update [dim].[company] set ModifiedOn = GETDATE() END
```

Update Execution Plan: Not sure its visible but it says Executions 1, Operator cost 0.040004 (92%)
[image]

Trigger Update Execution Plan: Not sure its visible but it says Executions 1, Operator cost 22.300197 (97%)
[image]

ANSWER:
Based on Emmad Kareem answer and this SO question - [trigger updates entire table even on single-row update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555424/trigger-updates-entire-table-even-on-single-row-update)

I changed the Trigger to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Dim].[Company_Update] ON [Dim].[Company] FOR UPDATE AS BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
update [dim].[company] set ModifiedOn = GETDATE() 
from [Dim].[Company] bf
inner join inserted i on i.CompanyKey = bf.CompanyKey
END
GO
```

Update now performs as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update trigger SQL does not have a WHERE clause to specify the specific row(s) you want to update.

Comment: How would I do that?  I assumed that the trigger was called once for each row that was updated and it knew which row that was.

Comment: @Stuart, sorry I was away. Glad you got it working. Just wondering about the contents of the column when the row is first inserted. I assume it would be null. Just be careful.

Comment: it has a default constraint of = GETDATE()

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a where clause on the trigger so basicly its updateing every row in the table every time.  try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Dim].[Company_Update] 
ON [Dim].[Company] FOR UPDATE 
 AS
 UPDATE [dim].[company]
  SET ModifiedOn = GETDATE()
  WHERE CompanyKey IN (SELECT DISTINCT CompanyKey FROM Inserted)
```